# Why is my close button not hiding my modal?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, modal-dialog

I get my modal to pop up when hitting the start button but why won't it close when I hit the close button? I can't even get the simple console.log to work when hitting the close button. Scratching my head on why this wouldn't work. I am using jQuery and the code of clicking on $startGameButton works and shows the modal but why doesn't the $closeStartModalButton work when clicking?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Wall Street Game</title>
    </head>
        <body>
            <header>
                <h1>So you want to make it on Wall Street?</h1> 
                <div id="#background-container">
                    <img id="background-photo" src="https://www.intelliventors.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/wall-street-bull.jpg">
                    <button id="start-game">Start Game</button>
                </div>
            </header>
    
            <div id="modal-container" class="modal">
                <div id="modal" class="modal">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit, officia ducimus illum ipsum inventore doloribus possimus, laborum quibusdam, ex sapiente corporis! Magni accusamus qui voluptatum, consequuntur ipsum itaque sint eum.</p>
                    <button id="close-button">CLOSE</button>
                </div>
            </div>
      
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="wallSt.css">
        <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="wallSt.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        </body>
    </html>

#modal-container {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;  
}

#modal {
 background-color:#fff;
 border-radius: 5px; 
 box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 padding: 30px 50px;
 width: 30vw;
 height: 30vh;
 max-width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 text-justify: center;
 display: none; 
 position: absolute; /*might need to delete this*/
}

#modal p {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    opacity: .7;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0%;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: justify;
}

#modal button {
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10%;
}

$(()=>{

//-----------------------------JQuery DOM ELEMENTS---------------------------------------
const $startGameButton = $('#start-game');
const $closeStartModalButton = $('#close-button'); 


$startGameButton.on('click',() => {
    $('#modal').show();
})

$closeStartModalButton.on('click',() => {
    $('#modal').hide();
    console.log('closed clicked');
})
})
```

Comment: The display none is on the modal, which is a child of the modal-container, and you are calling show/hide on the modal, not the container, so the container will always be visible.

Comment: Changed it to modal-container and it still doesn't work.

Comment: $startGameButton.on('click',() => {
    $('#modal-container').show();
})

$closeStartModalButton.on('click',() => {
    $('#modal-container').hide();
})                                                                                                                                                      Still didn't work